# Multiple Filter Options in a Search Function in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, search

[This is a UI page where users can be searched in a bootstrap table. And the users to search can be filtered using the 
              - registered time period
              - name
              - living area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDvGS.png)

I wrote the below js with two ajax calls where if none of the checkboxes are selected it is directed to the handler method to load the whole set of users.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#filterButton").click(function(){
    var from = $('#fromDate').val();
    var to=$('#toDate').val();
    var name=$('#cnameSearch').val();
    var city=$('#citySearch').val();

    if((from == "") && (to == "") && (name == "") && (city == "--Select--")  ){
        $.ajax({
            //type: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:8443/admin/users/view/customerTable",
            success: function (msg) {

                $('#tableCustomer').bootstrapTable('load', msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ajax failed" + uname);
            }
        });

    }else{
        $.ajax({
            //type: "POST",
            url: "https://localhost:8443/admin/userFilters/customerTable",
            data: {"from": from, "to": to, "name":name, "city":city},
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("ajax succ" + from +name +city);
                $('#tableCustomer').bootstrapTable('load', msg);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ajax failed" + uname);
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

And if any of the checkbox is selected, it is directed to another handler method where filter queries are called. Below is that handler method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customerTable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Map<String, Object>> dateFilteredStaff(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,
                                            @RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("city") String city)
                                            throws ParseException {


    //convert java.util time to sql time
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date fromDate= sdf.parse(from);
    Date toDate= sdf.parse(to);
    java.sql.Date sqlfromDate= new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqltoDate= new java.sql.Date(toDate.getTime());

    LOG.error("fromSql,{}",sqlfromDate);
    LOG.error("toSql {}",sqltoDate);
    LOG.error("name {}",name);
    LOG.error("city {}", city);

    List<Map<String, Object>> outc = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    //when both the date fields are filled
    if((!from.equals("")) && (!to.equals(""))){

     //call the database method to retrieve users filtered within a given date range
        List<User> customerList1= customerRepository.retrieveByDateRange(sqlfromDate,sqltoDate);

        for (int i=0;i<customerList1.size();i++){
            User customerUser=customerList1.get(i);
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("id", customerUser.getId());
            map.put("username", customerUser.getUsername());
            map.put("first_name",customerUser.getFirstName());
            map.put("last_name", customerUser.getLastName());
            map.put("mobile", customerUser.getMobile());
            map.put("email", customerUser.getEmail());
            map.put("address_line3", customerUser.getAddressL3());
            map.put("registered_date", customerUser.getRegDate());

            LOG.info("newUser {}", customerUser);
            outc.add(map);
            LOG.info("out {}",outc);
        }
    }

    //when only the from date field is filled
    if(!from.equals("") && (to.equals(""))){

   //call the database method to retrieve users filtered from a given date
        List<User> customerList2= customerRepository.selectbyStartingDate(sqlfromDate);

        for (int i=0;i<customerList2.size();i++){
            User customerUser=customerList2.get(i);
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("id", customerUser.getId());
            map.put("username", customerUser.getUsername());
            map.put("first_name",customerUser.getFirstName());
            map.put("last_name", customerUser.getLastName());
            map.put("mobile", customerUser.getMobile());
            map.put("email", customerUser.getEmail());
            map.put("address_line3", customerUser.getAddressL3());
            map.put("registered_date", customerUser.getRegDate());

            LOG.info("newUser {}", customerUser);
            outc.add(map);
            LOG.info("out {}",outc);
        }
    }

    return outc ;
}
```

But only when both the date fields are filled the filtering occurs. When 'to' date field is empty filtering doesn't occur. Could anybody please help me with this...

Still didn't write the logic for filtering using city and name. But I am intending to put that too in the same handler method with if condition checks....
Would that be OK..? Or should I write separate handler methods for that and call in a new ajax call.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance